# remove prefix from sigmaJS graph

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

How to remove the prefix from SigmaJS graph nodes & edges?

There are keys such as `read_cam0:size`, `read_cam0:x`, `read_cam0:y`, `renderer1:size`, `renderer1:x` and `renderer1:y` in the Sigma graph.

How can I remove those keys?

Is there any method I can call from the SigmaJS library to remove these keys?

I am new in SigmaJS and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to remove them ?

If sigma add those attributes, it's because it needs them to display the graph. So you can't remove them.

Cheers